# Java HttpClient SocketException & NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java

I take it simple.

Code:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
cm.closeExpiredConnections();
cm.closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost(proxyStr, 80);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 50);

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ip, port);
routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, true)) 
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
            .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy())
            .build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://*******);
List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA1", ***));
data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA2", ***));

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data, HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
} catch (Exception e) {

}

CloseableHttpResponse response2 = null;
try {
    response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
} catch(Exception e)...
```

The Error:

> Jan 12, 2018 8:43:40 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://89.19.249.55:3128->https://*****: Connection reset
>
> Jan 12, 2018 8:43:40 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
>   INFO: Retrying request to {tls}->http://89.19.249.55:3128->https:*****
>
> Jan 12, 2018 8:45:14 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
>   INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://184.178.217.66:3128->https://*****: The target server failed to respond

Ive extended the function with throwing Exceptions, but i cant catch them.

I think, its because they are Interrupts.

For your information:

The code is used by ~25 Threads.
One Error shutdown one Thread.
I cant check, if Thread is closed =/

so 25 Errors and my programm stuck...

Hopefully somebody knows how to fix this =/

Comment: It is unclear what you are aksing: Do you need help with catching the errors, or fixing the initial problem?

Comment: The best way would be fixing the problem, that causes the error.
But ive tried a lot, that there shall not be these interrupt.

So, if i cant fix this, i need to get around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With to Info of (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/RetryExec.html)

I would say, that this Interrupt/ Exception is thrown by  httpclient.execute(httpPost)

Later i can try it to fix and will inform you.

Comment: Its done. Just catch .execute...Do not try(.. Closeable...) catch... Just du try(Closeable() {....]} ;